# avg() return value type

Tags: sql, db2, decimal, average

I have two questions concerning average function in sql.

1. First of all I don't understand why does it return integer and not decimal number?
2. If you do casting for example avg(something * 1.0) how to make it 2 decimal?
   decimal(avg(something * 1.0),2) doesn't work...

Comment: Because DB2 does integer arithmetic on integers.  This applies to division and average.

Comment: Thanks, what about second question?

Comment: `avg(something * 1.0)` is _not_ casting. `CAST(something as DECIMAL(5,2))` is though.

Comment: Thanks, this topic can be locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 does integer arithmetic.  If you want two decimal places, I would convert the result to a decimal:

```
select cast(avg(1.0 * something) as decimal(10, 2))
```